# Performance penalty of ObjectBox assignable ids

Tags: android, database-performance, objectbox

ObjectBox docs suggest to use auto-assignable `long` ids for elements and it even has some checks based on it:

> By default object IDs are assigned by ObjectBox. For each new object, ObjectBox will assign an unused ID that is above the current highest ID value used in a box. For example, if there are two objects with ID 1 and ID 100 in a box the next object that is put will be assigned ID 101.

http://objectbox.io/documentation/introduction/#Object_ID_assignment

If we have a custom key, we can add `@Id(assignable = true)` and it will use given field as an id.

However, I read somewhere that it adds some performance overhead and it is better to use the standard auto incremented ones whenever possible. I can't find the source now, so does anybody know if it is ok to use assignable ids for often changed objects? In addition, does ObjectBox use `equals()` and `hashCode()` somehow?

The main reasoning for using assignable ids for us is to be able to `put` elements using their natural `long` ids without manual resolving the mapping.

Comment: Where did you read about the performance overhead?

Comment: It is possible that I just mixed it up with other information. If you say you don't know about it, I trust you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood according to official docs and comment of [Marcus Junginger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551269/markus-junginger) (CTO of ObjectBox), there is **no** performance penalty when you use assignable ids.